# Draw 3d model in XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, 3d, xna-4.0

I'm drawing several models, with the following code to set up render states:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

Some models rendered not correctly. If I change one line of code:

```
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
```

Now, others don't work correctly. I used 2 codes with each code segment but it still doesn't work.

How can i fix this rendering issue?

---

**Screenshots:**

I'm drawing the ground first, then the 'road' models.

Top: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH8qp.png

When I change angle of the camera...: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbw3m.png

Comment: Ok, I have just edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks to be [Z-Fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), a problem that is caused by trying to render 2 or more polygons at the same distance from the camera.

When drawing the models you could disable the Z-buffer. [`DepthStencilState.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.depthstencilstate.none.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you! If I use DepthStencilState.None, it render correctly. But, if I draw some models like house, human,..., these models always render under the 'road' model (same position). The road model always on top, overwrite these models. If I use DepthStencilState.Default, these model render correctly, them always on top, overwrite the road model, but my trouble in my post occur again. So I want to solve both problem: render correctly when I change camera's angle and order of all models are correct, how do I ?

Comment: If you disable the depth buffer, then it doesn't matter where models are drawn, earlier models will be hidden by ones drawn in the same place afterwards. I recommended this since you're drawing all your models at an equal distance from the camera (they are all on the same plane). Make sure you draw the ground, then the roads, then the house. If you want to use Z-buffering then draw the road slightly nearer to the camera than the ground, and the houses nearer still.

Comment: Yeah, thanks you very much. I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer.

Comment: Can I ask you more one question? Now, I draw some models on the ground and I want the models which nearly my camera will render first, all of models far to my camera will be hidden by them. But the model was drawn later, it rendered first and all models were drawn first, they were hidden. I mean perspective or another like that. Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but since it's a new qusetion, just post a new question on this site. By the way, as well as up-voting an answer, if you asked the question you can mark an answer as the best answer by clicking the green tick next to where you vote.

Comment: Okay, but Vote up requires 15 reputation. I have only 6.